# horizontal scroll is not working when using CSS only

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

i am trying to achieve horizontal scrolling using scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; with scroll to snap behavior. i am able to achieve the scroll to snap behavior but not the horizontal scrolling.
but if i hold shift and scroll it works ,also if i press t he arrow key it works. just doesn't work on mouse scroll

what can be the issue? can it be resolved using CSS only or JS will be needed?

CodePen link - https://codepen.io/manoranjanpanig/pen/dyWvzdK

HTML

```
<body>
   <div class="main-wrapper">
      <section class="one">
         <h1>First Page</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="two">
         <h1>Second Page</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="three">
         <h1>Third Page</h1>
      </section>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   overflow: hidden;
}
body{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
.main-wrapper{
   display: flex;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   scroll-snap-type: x mandatory ;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
section{
   flex: none;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 5rem;
   scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.one{
   background-color: aqua;
   
}
.two{
   background-color: salmon;
}
.three{
   background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example for horizontal scrolling and smooth scrolling /using smooth scrolling with css/:

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;

});
```

```css
main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  / this hides the scrollbars/ 
  display: flex;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* Please note that you have to use min-width and min-height ! */
```

```html
<main>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

Or you can use this method which uses js for smooth scrolling

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

  scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;

  });

  let = document.querySelector('#first', '#second', '#third', '#fourth');

  let el = document.querySelector('#home');
  let el2 = document.querySelector('#forMe');
  let el3 = document.querySelector('#work');
  let el4 = document.querySelector('#portfolio');


  first.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });
  second.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el2.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });

  third.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el3.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });

  fourth.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el4.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });
```

```css
main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  / this hides the scrollbars/ display: flex;
}

section {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <button id=first>Home</button>
    <button id=second>For me</button>
    <button id=third>Work</button>
    <button id=fourth>Portfolio</button>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <section id=home></section>
  <section id=forMe></section>
  <section id=work></section>
  <section id=portfolio></section>
</main>
```